# How can I do this if else statement?

Tags: c

When I use an `if`/`else` statement the last `else` has a red underline, and i debugged this program, it said `else` isn't paired with an `if`.

```
 /*문자 출력 프로그램*/

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)

{

char R, T, C, op;

    printf("문자를 입력하시오:\n");
    {
        if (R)
            scanf_s("%c", &R, sizeof(R));
        printf("Rectangular");

        if (T)
            scanf_s("%c", &T, sizeof(T));
        printf("Triangle");

        if (C)
            scanf_s("%c", &C, sizeof(C));
        printf("Circle");

        else (op == !!R, T, C);
    scanf_s("%c", &op, sizeof(op));
    }

    printf("Unknown");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you're missing `{}`, ex: `if (C) {
            scanf_s("%c", &C, sizeof(C));
        printf("Circle"); }`

Comment: `(op == !!R, T, C)` is, er, _novel_... Please pick up a text book rather than random hacking by Stack Overflow.

Comment: As well as the good information you have below, your very first test is wrong:  `if (R)` - You haven't given R a value at this point, so the test is meaningless, and the program can do anything (not just "either execute the then clause, or not execute it" - *anything*.)

Comment: There are many issues here, do you mean to do the scanf_s before the if checks?  And should you be checking for specific values that were scanned?  I.e.  if( R == 'R' ) { ... }?

Comment: You can now apply for a job as programmer at Apple! You are using the same coding style as they do and thus get the same kind of bugs. However, if you are otherwise looking for a career as a _professional_ programmer, always use `{ }` after every single statement in your code.

Comment: Also `else (op == !!R, T, C)` is complete nonsense, it is the same thing as writing `else (C)`.

Answer (score 2):

When your `if` has no brackets `{  }`, it'll consider only the first statement when executing. Since your `if` has more than one, the else won't work, because it's not after an `if` anymore.

Do this:

```
if (C)
{
   scanf_s("%c", &C, sizeof(C));
   printf("Circle");
}
else
{
   (op == !!R, T, C);
   scanf_s("%c", &op, sizeof(op));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The error on the `else` is quite correct, actually. Adding braces to show you what the compiler sees:

```
if (C) {
  scanf_s("%c", &C, sizeof(C));
}
printf("Circle");

// Now this else is really without a corresponding if
else (op == !!R, T, C);
```

As a general rule, you should use braces to make explicit what belongs to which conditional statement. In your case you probably meant to include the `printf` invocation in the block belonging to the `if` statement.

Note also that your `else` has a quite peculiar statement:

```
(op == !!R, T, C);
```

While this is *legal*, it doesn't really *mean* anything. At best it's an exercise in how to confuse the reader (barring any funny macro expansions). Heck, I couldn't even begin to interpret what you *might* mean with that.

Comment: I think the intention was to read a letter into `op` and then compare `if(op == 'R')` etc. so the code is very far from correct actually... the `printf` says "please enter a letter".

Answer (score 0):

As everyone here has already pointed out, you're missing the curly braces to connect the ifs with the else.  Also, I don't think this site should be doing your homework for you.  But here's an outline of what you should probably be attempting to code, by yourself!

```
char input;

// print request for user input (printf)

// read user input (scanf)

// check if user input represents a rectangle, then triangle, then circle, else unknown.
if( input == 'R') {
    // rectangle
} else if ( input == 'T' ) {
    // triangle
} else if ( input == 'C' ) {
    // circle
} else {
    // unknown
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Phiter and Joey answered, `{}` is the problem of error message about `else`.

And, `else` do not need any conditions. Your code looks like you intended "if input is not R, T nor C, scan again', right?

`else` means 'case that condition was not matched with above every `if` conditions', thus you don't need to write condition.

Anyway, first of all, it seems entire program has problem.
Read your textbook again, and mail to your TA.